# What code was used and are there any examples of code available to develop the MAM on the XDK and RuuviTag for the Tangle?

Tags: tangle, masked-authenticated-messaging

There have been reports of MAM being implemented and sent to the Tangle using the Bosch XDK and the RuuviTag. What code was used and are there any examples of code available to develop the MAM on the XDK and RuuviTag for the Tangle?